# Update Query said "ORDER_DETAILS"."QUANTITY": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, update

Update Query said `ORDER_DETAILS.QUANTITY` is an invalid identifier. I check and there is a table named `ORDER_DETAILS` with a field named `QUANTITY`.

```
Error at Command Line : 14 Column : 57
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ORDER_DETAILS"."QUANTITY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

///////////////////////////////////////////////

UPDATE 
(SELECT Orders.Order_ID, Order_Details.Quantity, Products.Units_In_Stock, Orders.Shipped_Date, Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN Orders 
INNER JOIN Order_Details ON Orders.Order_ID = Order_Details.Order_ID ON Products.Product_ID = Order_Details.Product_ID
WHERE ((Orders.Shipped_Date Is Not Null) AND (Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped='YES'))) 
SET Products.Units_In_Stock = Products.Units_In_Stock - Order_Details.Quantity;
```

Comment: I know that the select query above work because it returns three records as I expected. I just need to get it to update properly.                   SELECT Orders.Order_ID, Order_Details.Quantity, Products.Units_In_Stock, Orders.Shipped_Date, Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped
FROM Products 
INNER JOIN Orders 
INNER JOIN Order_Details ON Orders.Order_ID = Order_Details.Order_ID ON Products.Product_ID = Order_Details.Product_ID
WHERE ((Orders.Shipped_Date Is Not Null) AND (Orders.This_Order_Was_Shipped='YES'));

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+sql-update+join

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is a continuation of the following post.
[How to convert an Update a query from MS Access to Oracle SQL Software](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186206/how-to-convert-an-update-a-query-from-ms-access-to-oracle-sql-software/186215)

I kind of wish you would have continued our conversation there, but I guess they can be merged somehow.

I think you might have taken what I said literally and just switched ORDER DETAILS table to ORDER_DETAILS in your SELECT statement instead of changing the actual object's name.

The object's name was [ORDER DETAILS] and needs to be identified as "ORDER DETAILS" in ORACLE (with Quotes instead of brackets).  Try that and see.

**If not, and you actually did change the table itself to ORDER_DETAILS, then your issue is that you're using ORDER_DETAILS.Quantity in your SET.  That is not appropriate.  You NEED to give the subquery that the UPDATE wraps an ALIAS and say:**

```
SET Alias.OldValue = Alias.NewValue
```

You should set up your SELECT to retrieve the OldValue of the column, and the NewValue of the column.  Please see the link I included in my original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle

Comment: It's a continuation of a continuation ...

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Taking "subqueries" in the literal sense. :)